# Connect an existing wordpress database to the new installation

Tags: wordpress

I had a wordpress installation in sub folder of my root. The wordpress files got deleted accidentally but the database is still there and showing up in phpmyadmin. How can I proceed to connect a new wordpress installation to my old database. I tried adding the new wordpress files to the directory and changing wp-config.php with the existing database credentials. But it keep on redirecting me to wordpress setup wizard.
Can any one please help? How can I connect my existing database so that I can get my files and pages back.

Comment: its configuration file issue , did you check the table prefix in config file , it must be same as the table prefix in the existing db .

Comment: Thanku @Balwant. This solved my issue. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its configuration file issue , did you check the table prefix in config file , it must be same as the table prefix in the existing db